# Passing values between React components with useState

Tags: react-hooks

I use a React component with Apollo client as function component. The function body of my main search component looks like this:

```
function SearchContainer(props) {
    const [begTime, setBegTime] = useState('')

    const runSearch(begin_time) {
        console.log('begin_time: ', begin_time) <== The printed value is Ok!
        setBegTime(begin_time) <=== Use hook to set the value of begTime
        console.log('begTime: ', begTime)  <=== The output shows no change in begTime. Why?
    }

    return (
// Use SearchForm to get the search parameters.
        <SearchForm 
          handleSearch={runSearch} <== Use SearchForm to get begin_time back into this component.
        />       
// Provide the parameters from SearchForm and run the useQuery from Apollo using this parameters.
        <SearchResults
          begTime={begTime}
        />
    )
}
```

The SearchForm is just a usual form as a React function component with useState hooks and calls on form submit the hanldeSearch function.

```
function SearchForm({handleSearch}) { <== handleSearch function from the parent component.
   const handleSubmit = (begin_time) => {
       handleSearch(begin_time) <== This call works and the value will be provided to the parent.
   } 
...
}
```

My idea of this code is to create 2 independent components. One component (SearchForm) should get the parameters. The other component (SearchResults) will get this parameters as arguments, run the query using useQuery and show the results.

But the useState hook does not work very well in my case. Interesting enough if I call the corresponding search form twice, I can see in the runSearch function, that the begTime has got the previous search values and not the initial value. So apparently the useState kind of works, but I want to run the search with the current values and not with the previous ones.

Is it possible at all to create such components with React hooks? It's my first big test with hooks instead of classes.

Thanks in advance

Andrej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question

```
const runSearch(begin_time) {
        console.log('begin_time: ', begin_time) 
        setBegTime(begin_time) 
        console.log('begTime: ', begTime)  <=== The output shows no change in begTime. Why?
    }
```

**The output shows no change in begTime. Why?**
As stated in docs when we set state that is async function.

By that i mean your code will keep running and to set state react will start child process on another thread. And when its complete it will pass result to main thread. ( that you can c in useEffect or componentDidUpdate for early version).

So Main points are

1. at setBegTime(begin_time) async process is started
2. at main thread code will not wait for it
3. So next statement that is `console.log('begTime: ', begTime)` is processed and u saw no changes as in actual its value is not updated yet. React is still updating value.

---

Updating process is async because React dont want to main thread to wait for heavy work ( updating state is heavy process ) as if it wait then webpage will not respond untill it is completed. So it instead run that process on another thread.

---

For second one 
you can try this

```
function SearchContainer(props) {
    const [begTime, setBegTime] = useState('')
    const [response,setResponse] = useState({})
    useEffect(()=>{
    const runSearch = (begin_time) {
        setBegTime(begin_time) 
    }
},[begin_time])

// u can rather define working of handleSubmit in parent component and <br/>
// store its output in state and then pass it to another component
const handleSubmit = (begin_time) => {
       resp = handleSearch(begin_time)
       setResponse(resp)
   } 
        return (
    // Use SearchForm to get the search parameters.
            <SearchForm 
              handleSearch={()=>handleSubmit()}
            />       
    // Provide the parameters from SearchForm and run the useQuery from Apollo using this parameters.
            <SearchResults
              begTime={begTime}
              response={response}
            />
        )
    }
```